# Linking to javascript opens code instead of actual program

Tags: javascript, html

This might be a simple question to many of you but any help would be actually appreciated

```
<li><a href="rpsgame.js" onclick="myJsFunc();">rpsgame</a></li>
```

I am trying to link a tab to a cool simple game I made on Javascript, but it is opening in code instead of the actual program

My program name is rpsgame.js

Why is this happening ? what wrong did I do ?

Thank you so much

P.S: I'm new here!

Comment: I have a feeling you're misguided in some sense about the way JavaScript runs. To best explain the solution, could you tell me what you used to write and test your game? (For instance, if it was made in some game-creation tool)

Comment: I used notepad++ to write my game, I have not tested it since I do not know how. I am a beginner coder so excuse my misunderstanding in many aspects.

Comment: Ah. So the wording would be "a cool simple game I *am making*", not *made*. The answers below should be what you're looking for then.

Comment: no not I am making, I made, through javascript, however all i wanted to do is run it through an html page. It's  a simple rock scissor paper game

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is link the js file using the script tag.

Here's how to do it:

```
<script src="rpsgame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After you do that, when the user clicks on the tab, load using ajax the view you created above and thats it!

Comment: he's looking to run the  js at a user-determined time, but that will run it as the page loads

Comment: In that case, what you can do is when the tab is clicked, via ajax load tje script.

Comment: Just added the comment above to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are actually plain text, so you're only linking to a page of text. A few solutions follow:

1. Put the contents in a function in that file, add that file in a `<script` tag in the header, and call the function onclick
2. Or call in the file with AJAX and `eval` it, or maybe `JSON.parse` it, or whatever
3. make a function that adds a `<script>` tag to the header with that file as a `src`

Comment: And before somebody mentions this, the reason plain-text documents of server-side languages aren't returned as text in the browser is because the server processes them on request and only sends back the response, but the server does not handle javascript, so it just gives you the file in its entirety. Hope that helped

Comment: I think I understand
so would that be in the header of my javascript program ?

<script>
    function myJsFunc(){
        
    }
</script>

And what would i include inside ?
Thanks

Comment: Close, but it's actually a bit easier: `<script src="url/to/the/js/file" type="text/javascript"></script>`, and then add a call to `myJsFunc` to the element's onclick. (The closing `</script>` is necessary because the script tag isn't self closing)